# Quartz animation error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, quartz-core

I have included the `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` framework.

On an IBAction I have this:

```
- (IBAction)searchOptions:(id)sender {    
    FilterViewController *ctrl = [[FilterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FilterViewController" bundle:nil];
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:ctrl.view duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ctrl animated:NO];
}
```

When I click the button, the page curls up as you would expect:

When I click the next button (which should curl the page back down) I get this error:

**Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x8)**

I think the problem is with the above action (not with the action to uncurl).

What has gone wrong?

EDIT: After a further hour of reading - could it be a memory problem?

Comment: have u  #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> ?

Comment: I do, I have got this part working now - give me 2 secs will update question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but I don't think `UIView` retains the controller you're passing into it. Assuming you're using ARC, you could try making the `FilterViewController` into a property.

i.e. In the header add this:

```
@class FilterViewController;

@interface YourViewController : UIViewController {
    FilterViewController *_filterViewController;
}
```

Then in the implementation change it to:

```
 _filterViewController = [[FilterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FilterViewController" bundle:nil];
 [UIView transitionFromView:self.view _filterViewController duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:_filterViewController animated:NO];
```

To make sure it gets retained.

Comment: Hi! You are spot on with this I think, I just need some help implementing it if that is okay? I have FirstViewController and FilterViewController, FirstViewController curls up to show Filter, then Filter curls down to show First, which header do i put *_filter... in and *_first... Thank you SO much!!

Comment: Glad to help! And if this is the correct answer, feel free to mark it as such ;).
In your case, the easiest way is to let both viewcontrollers know about each other by giving them a pointer to one another. So basically FilterViewController gets the `@property (strong) FirstViewController *firstViewController;` and the FirstViewController gets the `@property (strong) FilterViewController *filterViewController;`. Then, in the overarching class (probably the AppDelegate), create both viewcontrollers and set the properties accordingly. Don't forget to use forward declarations in the headers.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment! Getting closer, still getting to grips with obj-c though! I have added the code and done a #import for the opposite header file but it errors: (FirstViewController) I have `@property (strong) FilterViewController *filterViewController;` and it says **Unknown type name FilterViewController, did you mean FirstViewController**

Comment: That probably means you didn't use forward declaration (`@class FilterViewController`) in the header.

Comment: Hi, sorry I know I am being thick here and thanks for bearing with me! It now has a new error (yey) http://i.imgur.com/Mgpaq4V.png if you like I can start a new question as this one has been answered - again thanks for your help! But if you know what this means I would appreciate some pointers :) I should also add, the error appears whenever I click any button/stepper on the revealed page after the fold, so its not just loading the view back that is a problem, genuinely am lost here!

Comment: It seems like you're not working with ARC (Automatic Reference Counting). I would definitely recommend it in your case because it will make problems like this (memory management) go away. If you don't feel like starting a new project, you can refactor your current project via `Edit -> Refactor -> Convert to Objective-C ARC...`. Note that ARC is supported from iOS 4.1+, so if for some reason you're compiling for an earlier version than that, you can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't really mandatory for you to do Page curling effect?

[Try this first]

```
- (IBAction)searchOptions:(id)sender { 
    FilterViewController *ctrl = [[FilterViewController alloc] init];
    ctrl.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
    [self presentModalViewController:ctrl animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion. Yes this works, I have used this previously - the reason I need to explicitly use the curlUp is because on the page shown by the curl I have a button which sets some parameters and then curls the page back down